# Display different view layout

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

i am developing with cakephp (2.4.7) and i want to know where is the best place (Controller, Model, etc) to write check functions to display different things (Buttons, Labels, ..) in the view.

**For example**, check if user has already liked a post (display "dislike" instead of "like") or check if users are friends and show "remove friend" instead of "add friend" button.

I know the question is very basic, but i don't know where i should place the code.

---

**What i have:**
*View*

```
$hasLiked = $this->requestAction('/userlikes/hasliked/' . $postId); // returns true/ false
if ($hasLiked) {
   $this->Html->link('Dislike', array('controller' => 'userlikes', 'action' => 'dislike', $postId));
} else {
   $this->Html->link('Like', array('controller' => 'userlikes', 'action' => 'like', $postId));
}
```

*UserlikesController*

```
    public function hasliked($postId) {
    if (empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }       
    return $this->Userlikes->hasliked($postId, $this->Auth->user('id'));
}
```

*Userlike Model*

```
    public function hasliked($postId, $userId) {

    $result = $this->find('count', array('conditions' => array('post_id' => $postId, 'user_id' => $userId)));

    if ($result == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

But i think my solution is very dirty, is there a better way? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to change your solution

*Userlike Model*

```
public function hasliked($postId, $userId) {

    return !empty($this->find('count', array('conditions' => array('post_id' => $postId, 'user_id' => $userId))));

}
```

*UserlikesController*

```
public function hasliked($postId) {
    if (empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }       
    $this->set('hasliked',$this->User->hasliked($postId,$this->Auth->user('id')));
}
```

*In your view*

```
<?php if($hasliked) :?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Dislike', array('controller' => 'userlikes', 'action' => 'dislike', $postId)); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Like', array('controller' => 'userlikes', 'action' => 'like', $postId));; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: First, thank you for your quick answer. Your solution is near what i already have. Is this the common way to implement such requests or is there a better way?

Comment: depends on what you need , i cant understand your controller action so i can give a tip

Comment: ah, you have used `$this->set('hasliked')..` but i don't have a view `userlikes/hasliked`, i only need this function in post/view. Thats why i have used requestAction. So what can i do now?

Comment: $this->set() should be used on whatever action you want

Comment: But i need to access the data from another view with requestAction. How can i retrieve the data with requestAction now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss one thing... Those features as Like, dislike, points etc are done by Ajax. So, make all your actions on simple and call them by Ajax. Like-

```
    public function like(){
    $this->autoRender = false; // If you wants to use this function just for ajax
     if($this->request->is('ajax')){
         // do something
         // capture all values send by Ajax and Call save function
     }else{
        return; // if not a ajax call, return
     }

   }
```

Its just an example----------
And one more thing, If you have thing to share same thing on View, better create `element`.

Comment: Yes i know, my problem is not the way of creating a new like my problem is to display different forms (like button, dislike button) in dependence of some actions (like, dislike). If you know what i mean..